# Writing python dictionary to a csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary called dict_object

```
dict_object=class_object.__dict__
print(type(dict_object))
print(dict_object)
```

This code gave the following output:

```
<class 'dict'>
{'name': 'abc', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'location': 'abc', 'degree': ['B. TECH COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING'], 'college': ['abc'], 'skills': ['Python', 'Java', 'C', 'C++', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MySQL', 'Figma'], 'companies': ['OASIS INFOBYTE', "LET'S GROW MORE", 'PERSISTENT SYSTEMS'], 'roles': ['Web Developer', 'Web Developer', 'Martian Internship Program'], 'degree_year': 2023, 'experience': 0.0}
```

I'm trying to write this dictionary into a csv file using the following code:

```
field_names = ['name', 'email', 'location','degree','colleges','skills','companies','roles','degree_year','experience'] 



with open('Names.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = field_names) 
    writer.writeheader() 
    writer.writerows(dict_object)
```

but it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

The error comes in the last line

Comment: Welcome to Data Science stack exchange! As this is a forum for data science related questions, it's better to ask programming questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking `writer.writerows`, which must receive an iterable (e.g. a list) of rows, but you are only passing one dictionary. You should either pass a list (e.g. `writer.writerows([dict_object])`) or invoke `writer.writerow`, which receives a single row.

Apart from that, there is a typo in a field: `college` vs `colleges`. In `field_names` you have `colleges` while in the object itself you have `college`.